# How to select first item in javascript object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am quite new to javascript/angular and was pondering whether or not there is an easy way to grab the first item in a javascript object/array.

EDIT: I do have control at this point in time in how I format the array, so perhaps there is a better way to do this using ID as keys?

Lets say I want to match the first item in the array. My thinking is to simply loop through the object checking the ID value.

The js function may look something like this:

```
app.controller('gamesController',function(){

    //Function to load the games
    this.loadGameIntoModal = function(game_id){

        for (i=0;i<=length(games);i++){
            if (games[i]['id'] === game_id)
            {
                   this.games = games[i]['id'];
                   //Load the modal
                   $("#game_modal").modal();
                   break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So my question is simply, is there a better way to do this than to use a loop?

```
var games = [

        {
        id   : 1,
        name : 'ABC Games',
        games : [
                {
                    id   : 1,
                    name : 'ABC 1',
                },
                {
                    id   : 2,
                    name : 'ABC 2',
                } ,
                {
                    id   : 3,
                    name : 'ABC 3',
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id   : 2,
            name : 'XYZ',
            games : [
                {
                    id   : 4,
                    name : 'XYZ 1',
                },
                {
                    id   : 4,
                    name : 'XYZ 2',
                } ,
                {
                    id   : 5,
                    name : 'XYZ 3',
                }
            ]

        }
    ];
```

Comment: As you are saying you do control the array: If the IDs are unique, you may use them as keys, such as `var game = {"1": {id: 1, name: 'ABC',...}, "2": {id: 2, name: 'XYZ',...} }`  and get them like `game[id]`, such as `game["1"]` and so on.

Comment: You could use `Array.filter()`. However is more or less the same as using a loop and performance wise it's going to make a difference. The loop can be terminated when found and isn't returning a new array. I think loop is the best option.

Comment: I am thinking loop may be the best option too. Or creating proper array keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different ways to do this, as other answers have valid suggestions. You mentioned that you're willing to restructure your object a bit. So this is an alternative that I've used:

```
var games = {
    1: {id   : 1,
        name : 'ABC Games',
        games : [
                {
                    id   : 1,
                    name : 'ABC 1',
                },
                {
                    id   : 2,
                    name : 'ABC 2',
                }
        ]
    },
    2: {id   : 2,
        name : 'XYZ',
        games : [
                {
                    id   : 1,
                    name : 'XYZ 1',
                },
                {
                    id   : 2,
                    name : 'XYZ 2',
                }
        ]
    },
}
```

With this structure, the ID is also the object's key. This has the advantage, that now you can just pass an ID, and reference it directly without loops. `games['1'].name //ABC Games`.

And just for convenience, we leave the `id` property within each object to make it easier for referencing later if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Select the object's first item's key:

```js
const items = { bill: 1231231, james: 545, scott: 8329, sarah: 999 };
const firstItem = Object.keys(items)[0]
console.log(firstItem)
```

Select the object's first item's value:

```js
const items = { bill: 1231231, james: 545, scott: 8329, sarah: 999 };
const firstItem = Object.values(items)[0]
console.log(firstItem)
```

It sounds like the person asking the question wants to **FIND** an item though in which case you would just use the `.find` method:

```js
const items = { bill: 1231231, james: 545, scott: 8329, sarah: 999 };
const keyContaining545= Object.keys(items).find(key => items[key] === 545)
console.log(keyContaining545)
```

... Or maybe he's asking for the first item in the array which is simply `games[0]`. The `[0]` is the position in the `games` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstProperty;
var firstValue;
for(firstProperty in target) { firstValue = target[firstProperty]; break; }
```

now firstProperty and firstValue should contain the first declared property key/value pair in the object or array ( key would be an int in this case ) of the object ( at least when I tested it with the `{}` syntax)

if you want to make sure it is the first property that belongs to that object can do this

```
for(firstProperty in target) if(target.hasOwnProperty(firstProperty)) { 
    firstValue = target[firstProperty]; 
    break; 
}
```

Like this solution because it is simple and doesn't require you to bring in another dependency if you don't need it

Comment: If it was any item in the array?

Comment: works for both array and object (only tested using `{}` syntax for object) use the second statement to filter out any properties from prototypes of the object

Comment: You need to be careful with this approach . . . in JavaScript, `Objects` do not have a guaranteed order for their properties.  With the way that he has his data set up (storing `Object`s in `Array`s), getting the "first item" will work, but it might not on another `Object` structure.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. In JavaScript, there is no guaranteed "order" of properties in and `Object` . . . only in `Arrays`, so, by far, the simplest way to make your data sequentially structured, is to use an `Array`.
2. If the only use of the `id` attributes is to indicate that order, you would be much better off using the indeces of an `Array` in to identify the different items, than a property within the object, since those indeces are more easily accessed.  I'd suggest updating your structure to this:

   ```
   var games = [
       {
           name : 'ABC Games',
           games : ['ABC 1', 'ABC 2', 'ABC 3']
       },
       {
           name : 'XYZ',
           games : ['XYZ 1', 'XYZ 2', 'XYZ 3']
       }
   ];
   ```

With that structure, you can still use a loop to iterate through the array structure, but you can also, very easily, access specific elements, using the indeces.  Some examples:

```
games[0].games[0] ---> "ABC 1"
games[1].games[0] ---> "XYZ 1"
games[1].games[2] ---> "XYZ 3"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you bring in a library like lodash (https://lodash.com) you can use their methods rather than handrolling it.

With lodash it'd be: `var firstItem = _.first(games)` (https://lodash.com/docs#first)

If you're familiar with .net, lodash is basically linq for JS.

Comment: ok if the items was any one of the items, how would it work? Or in this event it is a matter of looping through it.

Comment: You can use `_.filter` (https://lodash.com/docs#filter). Filter takes a function which you tell it how to filter things to find a result. or `_.find` (https://lodash.com/docs#find) if you're searching by id to find a specific result.